# Android Studio 4.1 Canary 9 201.6466190-linux distribution corrupted?

Tags: android-studio

At first I've tried to update Android Studio 4.1 Canary 8 to Canary 9 as usual through update dialog. At the first start Canary 9 have thrown error:

> Missing essential plugin:
>
> org.jetbrains.android
>
> Please reinstall Android Studio from scratch.

So I downloaded Canary 9 distribution from official source (https://developer.android.com/studio/preview). Deleted Canary 8 catalog and extracted tar.gz with Canary 9. Then launched `android-studio/bin/studio.sh` with the same error.

I renamed `~/.AndroidStudioPreview4.1` catalog and started studio once more. Same error.

Now I rolled back to Canary 8 from my backup.
Any help how to move from Canary 8 to 9?

Comment: Same here on Windows 10

Comment: i couldn't find any statement or expected new release , so i guess we'll have to wait

Comment: This is the preview release. You can find it by link in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically this issue mentioned in release notes

> In Android Studio 4.1 Canary 9, you may see the following error when
>   first launching Android Studio after upgrading:
>
> missing essential plugin org.jetbrains.android
>
> This can happen when you import your settings from a previous version
>   of Android Studio. Typically, this means you have a locally installed
>   Kotlin plugin that is not compatible with the new IDE.
>
> To fix this issue, remove the Kotlin directory from the following
>   locations:
>
> Linux: ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudioPreview4.1
>
> Windows:
>   C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudioPreview4.1
>
> MacOS: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudioPreview4.1
>
> Because there is no Kotlin plugin compatible with Canary 9 currently
>   available from JetBrains, we have bundled our own Kotlin plugin with
>   the Canary 9 update, so you don't need to manually install a Kotlin
>   plugin.
>   [source](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#4.1-ki-missing-kotlin-plugin)

At the same time by path `~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudioPreview4.1` no such file or directory. The only catalog named `AndroidStudioPreview4.1` founded by `./.cache/Google/AndroidStudioPreview4.1`. So I deleted it without any effect on subject issue.

Then I completely removed `~/.AndroidStudioPreview4.1` instead of renaming which I'd done before. And resolved the issue.

I believe Google bundle Kotlin plugin in a different way JetBrains do. So paths differ. Maybe path for Windows to. I believe paths should be corrected in release notes.

Solution:

`rm -r ~/.AndroidStudioPreview4.1`

Comment: I also had to not import the previous settings when starting Android Studio for the first time on Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

Solved this problem by using terminal in Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

```
toumbou@toumbou-Aspire-V3-471:~$ cd ~/.AndroidStudio4.0/config
toumbou@toumbou-Aspire-V3-471:~/.AndroidStudio4.0/config$ ls
codestyles  disabled_plugins.txt  inspection  plugins    tasks     user.token
colors      disabled_update.txt   options     port.lock  terminal  workspace
toumbou@toumbou-Aspire-V3-471:~/.AndroidStudio4.0/config$
```

and open the file via nautilus

```
toumbou@toumbou-Aspire-V3-471:~/.AndroidStudio4.0$ nautilus config
```

Then move the config folder and remove also the kotlinRefractoring.xml and also I removed the caches of my previous project so now I got it running fine again with some tweaks all things ares fine.

Comment: Thank you Brewton and sorry for my bad english