# Missing essential plugin: org.jetbrains.android Please reinstall Android Studio from scratch

Tags: android

While I was updating Android Studio to 4.0 my pc shutdown a and after that when I launched the android studio I got the  the following error.

[image: missing essential plugin error message]

I have tried this solutions but it is not working [Android Studio 4.1 Canary 9 201.6466190-linux distribution corrupted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61679948/android-studio-4-1-canary-9-201-6466190-linux-distribution-corrupted)

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling? ...

Comment: not yet but reinstalling is a hectic process.Isn't there any alternative other than reinstalling

Comment: Shouldn't take you more than a couple minutes. You don't have to reinstall emulators and SDKs, just the IDE. Maybe backup and move your prefs, though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio missing essential plugin org.jetbrains.android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61682609/android-studio-missing-essential-plugin-org-jetbrains-android)

Answer (score 12):

On Mac:

Go to: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.X

Delete:disabled_plugins.txt

Answer (score 2):

The plugins you should not disable : Kotlin, Smali Support, Gradle, Groovy, Properties, JUnit, IntelliLang. Also you may not disable Layoutlib Native and Layoutlib Standard. If you disable these, Project View - Android would be stuck loading...

---

This problem may be due to disabling plugins. This list is found by trial and may not be correct. (Tested on Android Studio 4.2, Windows 10)

If this problem occurs even you didn't disable these plugins, please follow this answer for deleting disabled_plugins.txt and try again. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61913060/14180528

Answer (score 1):

If anyone has the same problem in Linux, the directory is in the following path :

```
~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio2020.3/disabled_plugins.txt
```

Just open the `disabled-plugins.tx` file, Delete the line `org.jetbrains.kotlin`, Save and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

This situation, usually happens after you disable some essential plugins and restart the Android Studio.

For MacOS, Use following commands to reset Android Studio's configure files:

```
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.android.studio.plist
rm -Rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio*
```

For windows, I don't know the commands, but you can try to delete the following file:

```
C:\Users\admin\.AndroidStudio4.0\config
```

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work for me, as I don't have .AndroidStudio4.* or some folder like that under C:\User[MyAccountName]\. For my situation, should find out `disabled_plugins.txt` file from C:\Users\[MyAccountName]\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1, you can only remove the plugin which causes this problem from this text file or just remove this file if you cannot indicate which plugin is the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the link [here](https://blog.csdn.net/LQMIKU/article/details/108867209?spm=1001.2014.3001.5501), pay attention to this filePath: **~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio4.0/disabled_plugins.txt**